Two conjugated verbs - volvió hará
I am reading the book, Don de Lenguas by Rosa Ribas and Sabine Hofmann.
I encountered this sentence on p.143 and I don't know what to make of the two conjugated verbs side by side.

Vivió en el extranjero durante un tiempo después de la guerra, pero volvió hará un par de años.

I have tried a corpus, got chatgpt to give me an answer, but I really want exercises to practice what seems like a massive blindspot in my Spanish.
Thank you so much for your time and effort.

I would translate hará un par de años as something like a couple of years ago.  The purpose of the future tense hese is to convey a sense of vagueness.

On the one hand, the verb "hacer" can be used with periods of time to mean "ago":

hace un par de años: a couple of years ago

On the other hand, in Spanish the future can be used to express present probability, as can be read under 23.14h here:

Sabrás que ya no vivo aquí ~ Probablemente sepas que ya no vivo aquí; Estarán en la cafetería ~ Tal vez están en la cafetería.

and the verb "hará" in time constructions is just another example of this future of probability:

Vivió en el extranjero durante un tiempo después de la guerra, pero volvió hará un par de años = Vivió en el extranjero durante un tiempo después de la guerra, pero volvió probablemente hace un par de años.

The fact that the two verbs "volvió" and "hará" appear together does not mean that they are in any way related within the same verb phrase. Actually, phrases with "hacer" can be placed at the beginning of the sentence followed by "que" to introduce the main clause:

Vivió en el extranjero durante un tiempo después de la guerra, pero hará un par de años que volvió  = Vivió en el extranjero durante un tiempo después de la guerra, pero probablemente hace un par de años que volvió.


volvió (volver) = he returned
hace unos años = (hacer) a few years ago
hará un par de años = (hacer) = it will be a few years ago
“He lived abroad for some time after the war, but returned a couple of years ago.”

Thanks.
Could you also say?
Vivió en el extranjero durante un tiempo después de la guerra, pero volvió hace un par de años.
If yes, what is the difference between the two statements? Where can I practice this? Is it to do with doubt or probability?

Your sentence means the same thing. ‘Hará’ is the indicativo futuro and here it means “it will have been something like this”.
